# PHP command doesn't work unless you go to the folder where the script is

Tags: php, linux, command

when I run this command :

```
php -q /var/www/project/test.php
```

But it doesn't work unless I run this command :

```
cd /var/www/project/
```

Can you help me run this command witout executing CD ?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: No error , the script just doesn't run

Comment: Try this http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php

Comment: run without `-q` (quite) to see the error.

Comment: Should I see the error displayed on the console or the log ?

Comment: The content of the PHP file :
     <?php
     $fh=fopen('mail.txt','w');
     fwrite($fh,'Success');
     fclose($fh);
     ?>

Answer (score 0):

Fully qualify your `mail.txt` file. Change your php file to read:

```
<?php $fh=fopen('/var/www/project/mail.txt','w'); fwrite($fh,'Success'); fclose($fh); ?>
```

Comment: doesn't work , as you need to set var and www and project fully writable , I think this is a bad Idea

Comment: `/var/www/project/` must already be writeable for this to work when you `cd /var/www/project/`

Comment: `/var` and `www` do not need to be writeable for this to work. What happens when you `cd ; php -q /var/www/project/test.php` ?

Comment: Look at what happened, When I edited the test file I required a file in the same directory, but it gave the message Warning: require(facebook/src/facebook.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/project/classes/class_template.php on line 14
That means that there is a problem with the path when running commands

Comment: it said Could not open input file: /var/www/project/test.php

Comment: Failed opening required 'facebook/src/facebook.php'                                                                                         (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/project/classes/clas                                                                                        s_template.php on line 14
How come ?

Comment: `mv /var/www/project/facebook /var/www/project/classes/`

Comment: That's not the point, because the tree is valid , test.php is on the same level as facebook folder ..

Comment: But it's not test.php which can't find the facebook libray. Your include path only includes `.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear`. /var/www/project/classes/class_template.php will use this include path to find dependencies, such as the facebook library. That's why it works when you cd to `/var/www/project` because the facebook library is then on the include path. Either move the library or change the include path.